# How to access documentation for old version of Bamboo (pre 5.4)

Tags: bamboo

I'm trying to nail down the specific set of environment variables used for our 4.0 version of Bamboo that we're running. There's a set of deprecated variables I can run through listed in the 5.x documentation but I'd like to possibly jump to documentation that's relevant for our version of Bamboo. The web documentation's earliest version listed goes back to 5.4. Clicking on "Browse All Documentation" seems to just cycle back to the same versions ultimately :-(

[image: supported documentation for bamboo]

Is there a way to access documentation for earlier versions from our build server itself, through client access, or possibly any of the build agents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bamboo 4 is not supported anymore hence it was taken out from the version dropdown, which is already pretty long as it is.

For links to all existing Bamboo docs, go [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/alldoc/bamboo-documentation-directory-23855144.html).

Alternatively, you can access any documentation version by modifying the URL. For Bamboo 4.0, it looks like this:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO040/Getting+started+with+Bamboo

We hope this helps.

MM